# Mapping database column names to Java object variables

Tags: java, xml, database, mapping

I am looking for a framework or a solution that maps the column names of a database to variables of a Java object. 
Lets say I have a xml file that contains the element "docid" and its value. The database would contain a table with one column called "ducumentID". 
I want to compare the two values, so the one value inside the "docid" tag from the xml file and the data entry of the column "docid". Because in this example its just one thing I have to compare it would be easy to do this comparision manually. But later I want to do this with a dynamic count of values.
Is there some mapping framework or solution, where I can just say: this xml value is the appropriate value of that database column?

Comment: You are looking - http://www.hibernate.org/

Comment: Hibernate have all the tools you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/) is popular [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) that implements [JPA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Persistence_API).

Other ORMs for java:

- [OpenJPA](http://openjpa.apache.org/)
- Entity Beans in [EJB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_JavaBeans)
- [MyBatis](http://blog.mybatis.org/)
- [EclipseLink](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/)

Comment: Thanks for yout reply. I alreafy use MyBatis but for this application it is not useful. I will explain it in more detail:
Lets say i have a JavaBean with 3 variables: "docID", "date" and "title". Inside the database I have a table with the appropriate colums but with different names: Lets imagine these three: "documentID", "dateWhatever" and "doctitel". The values of each variable (database and xml content should be the same....this should be prooved by my application by the way)
With MyBatis I could set the Mapper.xml where I map the database column names to the object names. thats fine but..

Comment: when I make a select statement on the database with MyBatis, I get a resultset back. (I could do an insert statement for each culumn but that would be very ineffective) So when I have my resultset with the values of each database column....how can I compare them? MyBatis nows where to look it up in the database but when I get the resultset back, I dont know how the values can be compared.

Comment: For example I have to compare if "docID" equals "DocumentID"....but I only have the whole result set of the database and I dont know which column names maps to the appropriate variable name of my JavaBean. (ok I know it now but if I have 1000 variables it is impossible to know it exactly....therefore I need something like another mapping file or something like that)
I hope I could explain it well

Comment: You don't need to perform manual comparison between db column name and java object property. This is what ORM tool do. For example in hibernate you can add annotation on column with db definition:
`@Column(name = "documentID") long docId`

Answer (score 3):

you are looking for ORM framework.

here is list for ORM frameworks: [Wiki link for ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_object-relational_mapping_software)

In that [**Hibernate**](http://www.hibernate.org/) is Opensource and widely used framework.